# How to install specific parts of LibreOffice on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, libreoffice

I installed LibreOffice on Arch Linux and found some parts of it redundant. I don't want to use LibreOffice Base and LibreOffice Draw.

Is there a way to install a specific part  or uninstall a specific part of LibreOffice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Not anymore

The [Arch Linux Archive](https://archive.archlinux.org/) contains the 4.2.5 release of the individual compontents, which you can install individually, but note that [this is unsupported](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Linux_Archive#FAQ).  Later versions of LibreOffice do not allow components to be selectively installed.

Even if you wanted to bypass `pacman` (which you shouldn't), and download the 5.1 release directly from The Document Foundation, you would not be able to remove components.  You could forego installing the packages for Base and Draw, but the components are still installed.  The individual commands look like this:

**writer:**

```
#!/bin/sh

cmd=`dirname "$0"`/soffice
exec "$cmd" --writer "$@"
```

The other commands are similar, in that they all call `soffice` with a flag to denote the desired sub-program.  You can save one allocation unit of disk space per component by deleting the individual binaries from `/usr/bin`, but it won't remove the functionality.

Comment: Great first post.  I'd just like to add that `soffice` is yet another script, the actual compiled binary that runs `libreoffice` is `oosplash` (called from `soffice`).